# Share information between threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am an amateur to say the least, but I have made a few basic program.  Anyway, I am making a dvd changing robot.  The hardware side is already built, and works great with via the serial port.  In order to make this thing work I am going to have to make a multi-threaded app, my first.

The app will need at least 4 threads.  2 for 2 DVD recorders, one for the robot control, and one I am calling a director that will tell the other 3 threads what to do.

My problem is what is the best way to share data between these threads.  I have been looking around a little bit with shared classes, and threadlocks, but I get the feeling I may be over complicating things.  I know I could use a database to pass the data and have each thread check the database every few seconds, but that just doesn't feel to me like the right way to do this.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass any data you want to the `Thread.Start()` method. That's basically the preferred way of sharing stuff between threads. However, at a basic level, if more than one of the threads is going to access something that the others will as well, you need to establish some kind of locking mechanism to ensure you don't have contention issues.

Let's say you have a class instance at the global level that is shared among your threads:

(this is C# but you get the idea)

```
class GlobalData {

    public string SomeProperty {get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherProperty {get; set; }

}
```

A scenario where more than one thread accesses any of these properties at the same time (or expect the value to be consistent across calls) would be trouble. So the easiest way is to create a locking mechanism where the thread is responsible:

```
class GlobalData {

    public object Sentry = new object();

    public string SomeProperty {get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherProperty {get; set; }
}
```

In the code that runs the threads, you would do something like this (assuming `g_Data` is the instance of the class):

```
void SomeMethodRunningOnAThread() {
    lock (g_Data.Sentry) {
        // do stuff    
    }
}
```

(in VB.NET the equivalent to `lock` is `SyncLock`)

This is the simplest way to ensure you don't get into contention issues. Each thread is responsible for ensuring that they are attempting a lock on the object before accessing its contents.

Beyond that, there are of course ways to finesse this, such as implementing the lock logic within the class that contains the global data. It doesn't get *less* complicated, so if you want to implement something more complex in the end you'll have to read up anyway.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, and I am probably missing something simple.  But, if make an new instance of the class (g_data) how would the other threads access it since they would have their own instances of g_data?  I thought I would have to use something like a shared member so that the threads could pass the data between them?

Comment: The example here assumes that g_Data is a global instance held somewhere which is shared by all the threads. E.g., a single global instance of a class.

Comment: Thanks kprobst, I have never made a global instance, looks like I need to do some google searching and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Ok I have been banging my head against this, and I seem to still be having trouble.  Every synclock example I see assumes that what I want to synclock is in the same class as where I am making the thread.

If I had a class called, lets say threadinterface, how would I write that and use it in a different class and still be able to share the data across many threads?

Comment: Success, I was making a bad assumption about the way shared members work.  Once I sat back and thought about it, I came up with a solution.